# Silverlight equivalent of Flex's includeInLayout property?

Tags: silverlight, apache-flex, silverlight-4.0

Do Silverlight components have a property similar to Flex's `includeInLayout` property? I'm looking for something that will allow a Silverlight component or container to grow and/or shrink without affecting its neighbors or parents positioning or size.

Comment: Canvas is the most likely candidate for your situation. In Silverlight your control layout by using appropriated hierarchy of containers.

Comment: @Denis If I have the `Canvas` in another container like a `Grid` or `StackPanel` and the `Canvas` grows larger than the parent container, will the parent container stretch until the `Canvas` can fit?

Comment: Canvas itself can affect size of parent Grid, but Canvas will not change its owns size if child control changes size or position. Effectively Canvas will isolate its children from layout process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is only the Visible property (Visible/Collapsed). In the past I had to put whatever I wanted to hide in a container that was either statically sized or not sized to wrap it's contents (so that it still took up space). If the you use a container for only this purpose be sure to clean up any padding, etc.

Visibility Property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do using UIElement.RenderTransform will not update layout, so you can scale, translate, rotate without affecting the elements around.